# How to first-run using Pickle

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pickle

I need to be able to identify a first run using Pickle.
So that my program knows when to ask for a new User.
Sorry if my lingo isn't right.
I need it so that on the first run, the program asks for a new user, saves the name using pickle and then plays the welcome sound. On other runs it should load the profile and play one of the Welcome back sounds. Im having trouble identifing the first run

```
import random
import pickle
import configparser
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import scrolledtext
import time
root = Tk()

data = {}
def Normal():
    greet = input ("What would you like to do Operator? \n a) Arsenal \n b) Navigation \n c) Codex \n d) Market \n e) Mods \n f) Foundry \n g) Incubator \n h) Void Relic Segment \n i) Helminth Infirmary \n j) Personal Quarters \n k) Missions \n")

def GreetingOrdis():
    foo = [r"C:\Users\arnold\Downloads\OrdisL1.mp3",r"C:\Users\arnold\Downloads\OrdisL2.mp3",r"C:\Users\arnold\Downloads\OrdisLogIn2.mp3",r"C:\Users\arnold\Downloads\OrdisLogIn3.mp3"]
    secure_random = random.SystemRandom()
    playsound(secure_random.choice(foo))
    root.after(1000, Normal)

try:

    with open('info.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
        data = pickle.load(handle)
        data = firstrun = 1
        if firstrun == 1:
            root.after(1000, Normal)   

except:
    data = {'Name': input("What is your name operator?: ")}
    data = [firstrun == 1]
    playsound (r"C:\Users\arnold\Downloads\OrdisLogIn2.mp3")
with open('info.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(data, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    root.after(1000, Normal)
```

Comment: In what way are you "having trouble"? Be specific about what is happening wrong.

Comment: @martineau What I need it to do is:
When opened for the first time - save a variable (firstrun) as 1 
In subsequent openings it would notice that it has run b4 and then do something else, eg. Greet instead of asking for a username

Answer (score 0):

This shuld solve some of the problems, if you want a time related such as day first run just bind the time in days to the `data`, like `data['last_run'] = current_day`.
Using `try` is not ideal to see if a file exist, `os` functions will do a better work.

```
import random
import pickle
import configparser
import time
import os

# It is not a good practice import a module with *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# take as a global the dir in witch is this file
PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

root = tk.Tk()
data = {}


def Normal():
    # To make a multi-line str use triple quotes (can be used to comment a line)
    greet = input("""What would you like to do Operator? \n 
                        a) Arsenal \n 
                        b) Navigation \n 
                        c) Codex \n 
                        d) Market \n 
                        e) Mods \n 
                        f) Foundry \n 
                        g) Incubator \n 
                        h) Void Relic Segment \n 
                        i) Helminth Infirmary \n 
                        j) Personal Quarters \n 
                        k) Missions \n""")


def GreetingOrdis():
    foo = [r"C:\Users\arnold\Downloads\OrdisL1.mp3",
           r"C:\Users\arnold\Downloads\OrdisL2.mp3",
           r"C:\Users\arnold\Downloads\OrdisLogIn2.mp3",
           r"C:\Users\arnold\Downloads\OrdisLogIn3.mp3"]

    secure_random = random.SystemRandom()
    playsound(secure_random.choice(foo))
    root.after(1000, Normal)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # if there is no comparator it will handle it as 'x == True'
    # a quicker way to check is looking if the file exist
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(PATH, 'info.pickle')):
        # pickle stores data in bites, to read leave the default
        with open('info.pickle', 'rb') as file:
            # data is a dictionary, the file should be as well a dictionary
            data = pickle.load(file)   # Load the file content
            data = pickle.loads(data)  # Load the data from the file

            # changes to not first wen is first
            if data['first_turn']:
                data['first_turn'] = False
                root.after(1000, Normal)

                print('First')
            else:
                print('Not first')

    else:
        name_input = input("What is your name operator?: ")

        data = {
            'Name': name_input,
            'first_turn': True
        }

        playsound (r"C:\Users\arnold\Downloads\OrdisLogIn2.mp3")

    # using join mean the file is searched in this file directory
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(PATH, 'info.pickle')):
        # 'wb' is to write as bytes
        with open(os.path.join(PATH, 'info.pickle'), 'wb') as file:
            # to save a pickle first convert it to "pickle" format (bytes)
            pickle_data = pickle.dumps(data)
            pickle.dump(pickle_data, file)
    else:
        # 'xb' is to create a new file and write as bytes
        with open(os.path.join(PATH, 'info.pickle'), 'xb') as file:
            # to save a pickle first convert it to "pickle" format (bytes)
            pickle_data = pickle.dumps(data)
            pickle.dump(pickle_data, file)

        root.after(1000, Normal)
```

Comment: First I got this error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/arnol/Pictures/Fixed.py", line 53, in <module>
    data = pickle.loads(data)  # Load the data from the file
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'dict'`
Then I got this error when I changed loads -> Load
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/arnold/Pictures/Fixed.py", line 53, in <module>
    data = pickle.load(data)  # Load the data from the file
TypeError: file must have 'read' and 'readline' attributes`

Comment: I teststed it, without `playsound`, by best gueast is to delete the pickle file and use the file witch generates, the files shuld be _bites-like_ and a `dumps` shuld be a serialization string.